# how to find pickle files created by joblib

Tags: python, joblib

Joblib uses pickle to pass object to child process. Where are those pickle files stored? I got IOError when running parallel jobs because pickle files fill the disk space. They need to be deleted.

Comment: You can search for `*.pkl` (usually used with joblib) files and manually delete them